# 404 :-( Page not found ! No query results for model [App\Models\City] 0

Tags: php, laravel

I am having issue with the models 
404
 :-( Page not found !
No query results for model [App\Models\City] 0
How can this be fixed?  on local serve I don't get this issue.This is only happening on the live server whereas on localhost it doesn't give such issue.

```
herenamespace App\Models;

use App\Helpers\Number;
use App\Models\Scopes\ActiveScope;
use App\Models\Scopes\LocalizedScope;
use App\Models\Traits\CountryTrait;
use App\Observer\CityObserver;
use Larapen\Admin\app\Models\Crud;
```

class City extends BaseModel
  {
    use Crud, CountryTrait;

```
/**
 * The table associated with the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'cities';

/**
 * The primary key for the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
// protected $primaryKey = 'id';

/**
 * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
 *
 * @var boolean
 */
public $timestamps = true;

/**
 * The attributes that aren't mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
// protected $guarded = ['id'];

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'country_code',
    'name',
    'asciiname',
    'latitude',
    'longitude',
    'subadmin1_code',
    'subadmin2_code',
    'population',
    'time_zone',
    'active',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays
 *
 * @var array
 */
// protected $hidden = [];

/**
 * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| FUNCTIONS
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    City::observe(CityObserver::class);

    static::addGlobalScope(new ActiveScope());
    static::addGlobalScope(new LocalizedScope());
}

public function getAdmin2Html()
{
    $out = $this->subadmin2_code;

    if (isset($this->subAdmin2) && !empty($this->subAdmin2)) {
        $out = $this->subAdmin2->name;
    }

    return $out;
}

public function getAdmin1Html()
{
    $out = $this->subadmin1_code;

    if (isset($this->subAdmin1) && !empty($this->subAdmin1)) {
        $out = $this->subAdmin1->name;
    }

    return $out;
}

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| RELATIONS
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'city_id');
}

public function subAdmin2()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(SubAdmin2::class, 'subadmin2_code', 'code');
}

public function subAdmin1()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(SubAdmin1::class, 'subadmin1_code', 'code');
}

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SCOPES
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ACCESSORS
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
public function getAsciinameAttribute($value)
{
    return preg_replace(['#\s\s+#ui', '#\' #ui'], [' ', "'"], $value);
}

public function getLatitudeAttribute($value)
{
    return Number::toFloat($value);
}

public function getLongitudeAttribute($value)
{
    return Number::toFloat($value);
}
```

link for the error https://www.clusify.com/en/free-ads/new-york-city/5128581

404
 :-( Page not found !
No query results for model [App\Models\City] 0
How can this be fixed?  on local serve I dont get this issue.This is happening only on the live server which is on shared hosting space.

Comment: Do you have your live server's database populated?

Comment: you mean if the database live ? if then yes its live

Comment: Noting the specific `0` at the end of your error message, it looks like Eloquent is trying to retrieve a City model with an ID of `0`. Without knowing how you're specifically trying to retrieve the City, I would check any foreign keys referencing a `city_id`, and see if any have a value of `0`. Then, identify why that happened and fix any bugs. :)

Comment: In the stacktrace, you will see the line the code breaks on can we get that, somewhere you do a Model::find(0); or logic that makes the id become 0